# Is there a way to link the Google Identity Token to my company user in the database?

Tags: oauth-2.0, actions-on-google, google-authentication

I'm setting up an action on google project which uses the OAuth & Google Sign In Linking Type.

Previously, I was using the userId that was sent in every request to look up the user in the database to see if there were accesstokens and refreshtokens available. But since userId is deprecated, I am looking for an alternative.

The user starts his/her dialog and then bumps into this piece of code:

```
app.intent('Give Color', async (conv, { color }) => {
  conv.data[Fields.COLOR] = color;
  if (conv.user.ref) {
    await conv.user.ref.set({ [Fields.COLOR]: color });
    conv.close(`I got ${color} as your favorite color.`);
    return conv.close('Since you are signed in, I\'ll remember it next time.');
  }
  return conv.ask(new SignIn(`To save ${color} as your favorite color for next time`));
});
```

The "To continue, link Test App to your Google Account" on which the user selects the correct Google account.Then my /token endpoint is called on the OAuth server containing the Google ID Token (assertion) which holds all of the users data. I decode it, check in the database if the "sub" is already present, and I throw the following exception:

```
return res.status(401).send({ error: 'user_not_found' });
```

Then the normal OAuth procedure kicks in, where I deliver a token to Google. Sidenote: this is my own OAuth Server written in NodeJS. I am sure that the access- and refreshtoken are delivered to Google.

After token delivery, I get a new request on my action:

```
app.intent('Get Sign In', async (conv, params, signin) => {
  if (signin.status !== 'OK') {
    return conv.close('Let\'s try again next time.');
  }
  const color = conv.data[Fields.COLOR];
  await conv.user.ref.set({ [Fields.COLOR]: color });
  return conv.close(`I saved ${color} as your favorite color. `
    + 'Since you are signed in, I\'ll remember it next time.');
});
```

The signin.status has a value of "OK". But shouldn't the conv.user object contain the Google ID Token so that I can store the access- and refreshtoken along with this "sub" from the Google ID Token in my database? Or am I getting something wrong?

The content of the conv.user looks like this:

```
User {raw: Object, storage: Object, _id: undefined, locale: "en-BE", verification: "VERIFIED", …}
_id: undefined
[[StableObjectId]]: 7
access: Access {token: "ACCT-ATlbRmcpMI545WJFssRSlK1Jcza46NIB"}
entitlements: Array(0) []
id: undefined
last: Last {seen: Thu Aug 08 2019 10:53:17 GMT+0200 (Central Europea…}
locale: "en-BE"
name: Name {display: undefined, family: undefined, given: undefined}
permissions: Array(0) []
profile: Profile {token: undefined}
raw: Object {accessToken: "ACCT-ATlbRmcpMI545WJFssRSlK1Jcza46NIB", locale: "en-BE", lastSeen: "2019-08-08T08:53:17Z", …}
storage: Object {}
verification: "VERIFIED"
__proto__: Object {constructor: , _serialize: , _verifyProfile: , …}
conv.user.id is *DEPRECATED*: Use conv.user.storage to store data instead
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't contain the Google ID of the user, because the user hasn't authorized that.

What they *have* authorized is whatever you've asked them to authorize via your OAuth server.

So you'll see the access token that your server has sent to the Assistant in `conv.user.access`, and you can then use this token to lookup who the user is in your database and take action accordingly.

If you specifically want their Google ID, you'll need to make sure that they use Google Sign-In on the same project as your Action (either through voice, a mobile app, or a webapp).

If you just need an ID so you can see when this user returns later, you can use the Google ID you get from Google Sign-In, or just generate an ID and store this in `conv.user.storage`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

I indeed see the access token that my OAuth server has sent to the user. But I don't get the complete flow of this. Is it maybe possible to give me more details on this? Like which action I should perform where? 

Thanks in advance man! Really appreciate your help!

Comment: It depends what you mean by "what action [you] should perform where". Your original question made it sound like you just needed the auth token, which using OAuth should do. I've added a paragraph about various ways to get reference IDs as well, but if you need more, you can update your original question to clarify exactly what you're trying to get or what further details you need.

Comment: Ok, I'm coming back to this sentence of you:

"So you'll see the access token that your server has sent to the Assistant in conv.user.access, and you can then use this token to lookup who the user is in your database and take action accordingly."

Do you mean that I might have to look up the access token that is sent in the request in my database, and if there is no google ID linked to that token, that I then should ask for the new SignIn?

Answer (score 0):

Since I just want to have an ID, I will be using this:

If you just need an ID so you can see when this user returns later, you can use the Google ID you get from Google Sign-In, or just generate an ID and store this in conv.user.storage.

Thanks!